# External stylesheets either not downloading or not being applied in very rare cases

Tags: html, css, browser, stylesheet

I recall some very rare instances of seeing major websites (Amazon, Facebook, etc.) either not downloading a CSS file or not applying the rules, causing the page to look like this:

[image: style-less Facebook]

I've been tasked to provide an internal explanation after we received a complaint email with an attached screenshot from a user of one of our websites showing the same effect. The screenshot contains sensitive user information, so I'm unable to post it. But it shows that inline styles are being applied, but any style referenced from an external CSS file isn't being applied.

Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce this issue, and other than just saying "styles aren't being applied", I am coming up dry with a detailed explanation and I would love to understand it myself.

I would appreciate any input on why this might happen, or reference to any articles. Even if someone knows what this event is called, I would be happy to go research it, but as of now I'm coming up blank.

Comment: make sure that the external sheet's url is set correctly (e.g. when offline it might be localhost/css/style.css and online it might be example.com/css/style.css), check the spelling of the tab, and make sure that there isn't an error anywhere else in the html (http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: @Markasoftware Thanks for the response. The website is a professional site with a development team behind it. We have test teams to ensure paths are all correct, so incorrect paths are known not to be the issue.

Comment: Could you provide us the website URL and the browsers affected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are more than one scenarios under which this can occur:

1) **bandwith issues** : as italo.nascimento mentioned, a slow connection, where your HTML is downloaded but your CSS is timed-out so you're left with a naked HTML page (happens often also when a website is under DoS or has many many visitors and the server can't keep up with the traffic)

2) **caching problems** : something is changed in your HTML, but the CSS is served from the browser's local cache so the selectors don't match...

3) **FOUC** : It's not really similar to what you're asking, unless the printscreens were made during the page load.. It's called Flash of Unstyled Content.

In general 90% of these kinds of problems are cause by connection issues. Dropped packets, TimeOuts, CDN's not working properly.. And as they are random I don't think you can "reproduce them" - it's not something that can get fixed.

Comment: Rather than post a separate answer, I'll add to this excellent explanation a suggestion that network-related timeouts when loading  CSS could be mitigated (though not eliminated) by combining and minifying your CSS files. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx

Comment: Thanks - Indeed, the less http requests, the smaller the possibility for a problem gets..

Comment: I'd say this particular case can be easily explained by CDN (Content Delivery Network) failure. Large sites usually use separate servers for hosting their static content to speed up delivery - if the network serving these files has issues, the dynamic HTML will load, but not any of the external assets. Good thing - this is very rare, bad - there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos, thank you for the information. In our case, it was an unusually large traffic volume that was going to hit the site. We thought about hosting CSS and JS files on a CDN but decided against it. Now we know better! Thanks!

Comment: @JacobM Thank you for the blog post. That is some useful information and tools.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me lots of times in major sites.

Mostly, it happens when Internet connection is very slow or oscilating, so the files doesn't load correctly from the server (packages get lost) and the site is showed in pure HTML. Maybe you could reproduce it by limiting your bandwidth and reloading the page.

Comment: This. If a customer ever sees it happen again, if they hit F12 and check out the network info you're pretty much guaranteed to see that the CSS failed to download for one reason or another. There are hundreds of reasons why the CSS could fail to download, the fact that modern networking works as well as it does is a testament to the folks that built it.